# Does putting a key in a capsule mean you can hack more?

Tags: ingress

If I put a portal key inside a capsule, can I keyfarm without dropping it, or does having it in there still count as inventory and prevent me from getting more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[According to decodeingress.me](http://decodeingress.me/category/game/updates/), yes:

> **Can I use Capsules for key farming?**
>
> Most definitely. When you put a key into a Capsule, the portal you are hacking will not recognize it, almost guaranteeing you a key on your next hack.

Comment: Well, ~70% is not "almost guarantee" in my book … but other than that, correct.

Comment: Not "most" definitely. *Definitely*. I got 100 keys from the very same portal in a capsule

Comment: Why would you want 100 keys from the same portal?

Comment: @ssmith world domination

Comment: @ssmith you want many keys for creating fields over and over with using portal