# Portal Keys and Capsules

Tags: ingress

Can you store more than one of the same key in the same capsule?  Providing of course you have enough room etc.

I noticed that you can only hold one of the keys, as the portal doesn't give you one if it picks up you already have one. I have a key in my inventory as well as in a capsule. I am not sure if I should try adding it to the capsule without losing it. Can anyone clarify that you can store multiple keys in the same capsule?

Comment: Your question looks like the same as this one (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166894) with only one difference that you're asking specifically about stacking more than one key in a capsule whereas this question has this information on the comment of its answer.

Comment: Anyone able to mark this as duplicate?  I don't have the rank to do it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can store more than one key in the same or in different capsules. This enables you to not drop keys anymore to get more from hacks.

Comment: Hopefully this question proves helpful to others!  Will accept after 10 minute cooldown